# Full screen issue with flash player

Tags: 14.04, gnome, firefox, flash

I have an issue regarding flash player, in some cases it works perfectly fine (Youtube), but when trying to use the full screen feature on Facebook or Twitch.tv it succeeds the first time, however if i Hit ESC to leave the full screen and try to enter it again afterwards, the video will freeze. In this case i have to restart Firefox to be able to obtain a full screen again.

Im running on ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME3 Desktop.

Im open for any suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's the same with version 11.2.202.418, I updated adobe flash and the problem appeared.

I fixed it by reinstalling the version 11.2.202.233